# Running a K8S Deployment with pods scheduled in ARM-based and X68-based nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a raspberry pie cluster( ARM-based CPU ) and a couple of virtual machines that run on an X86 based laptop, I was able to establish a K8S cluster atop my raspberry pie cluster and the other X86-based virtual machines .

I want to run a K8S deployment in this cluster with  pods running the ARM-based docker image in Raspberry pie nodes and other pods running X86-based docker image in my X86-based virtual machines .

I wonder if there is any easy way to achieve this . Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Selector/Affinity mechanisms and `beta.kubernetes.io/arch` [label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/labels-annotations-taints/) of the node which automatically assigned to each of them.

You can call `kubectl describe node $nodename` and check that label. On X86 it will be `beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64`, on ARM it will be different.

So, for X86 payload you can add node selector:

```
nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
```

Then K8s will spawn that payload only on X86 servers. 
The same thing you can do for your ARM payload.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, my question is whetehr if it is possible to specify separate container image per node architecture in the same Deployment manifest, I know that it is possible to have two different deployment scheduling pods in arm-based or x86-based  nodes, but I want to have a single Deployment manifest controlling pods running into diffrent cpu-architure nodes

Comment: Docker supports in out-of-the-box if your image has builds for architectures you need. To learn how to build that kind of images yourself, try to check [BuildX](https://github.com/docker/buildx/). But, you cannot specify images by architecture, it should be the same image and tag which contains images for multiple archs.